# Zurb Foundation grid gives me height, reflow issues

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation

One of the core components in Foundation fails on me. Seems to be a flaw in foundation grid.

This img says it all - 'smalll':
[image: grid-fails]

Here is a Fiddle as well, make sure you resize the window to 'small',

```
small-6 large-3 columns is the classes used.
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/ePJzw/)

So 4 columns on desktops - and 2 on small displays.
The same problem was happening for desktop as well - but I made a  for every fourth column. So the desktop columns works nicely. Even though it would be nicer to not be needing to do that as well.

But the 'small' displays has the issue that is seen in the fiddle and screenshot. Because here there will still be 4 columns inside a , but will be split up on two rows.

Is there a simple fix for this? Javscript equal heights probably someone says. But then it has to be triggered on resize, and only when the "small" mediaquery is the active one. And only for the product on the left to match the height of the product on the right. And I am not good at javascript.

So is there anyone having a fix for this?
This seems to be a huge flaw. I am almost certain there must be a smart fix for this?

Easiest and most convinient solution is to skip the small-6 and only have all products stacked.. but is is not the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

The very best way with foundation to set up a block grid is to use the [block-grid elements.](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block-grid.html)

The way to use the block grid and for the small screen it will show the elements two up and on the large screen you will get four up.  One of the very best things about foundation.

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
  <li><img src="../img/demos/demo1.png"></li>
  <li><img src="../img/demos/demo2.png"></li>
  <li><img src="../img/demos/demo3.png"></li>
  <li><img src="../img/demos/demo4.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Your code rewritten.

```
<div class="products-list-container">
  <ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
    <li>
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img width="150" height="150" src="http://u3065104.fsdata.se/wplove/wp-content/uploads/Bodybutter-Cocos.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Bodybutter Cocos"></div>
        <h3>#1 When first columns is higher then the one to the right. There is a big bug happening. This is by all means not good at all. This makes me this grid to fail for many cases. Am I missing something obvious?</h3>
        <span class="price"><span class="amount">115kr</span></span>
    </li> <!-- .product end -->

    <!-- .product start -->
    <li>
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img width="110" height="200" src="http://u3065104.fsdata.se/wplove/wp-content/uploads/Lavera-Solskydd.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Lavera Solskydd"></div>
      <h3>#2 If this would be having higher height than the one to the left - no problem</h3>


      <span class="price"><span class="amount">210kr</span></span>
    </li> <!-- .product end -->

    <!-- .product start -->
    <li>
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img width="336" height="506" src="http://u3065104.fsdata.se/wplove/wp-content/uploads/CottonButton-nattlinne-cherry-336x506.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Cotton&amp;Button nattlinne cherry"></div>
      <h3>#3&nbsp;Ekologiskt nattlinne cotton &amp; button</h3>

      <span class="price"><span class="amount">375kr</span></span>
    </li> <!-- .product end -->


    <!-- .product start -->
    <li>
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img width="400" height="400" src="http://u3065104.fsdata.se/wplove/wp-content/uploads/Ekologiska-kakaomandlar-400x400.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Ekologiska kakaomandlar"></div>
      <h3>#4 Ekologiska kakaomandlar</h3>

      <span class="price"><span class="amount">99kr</span></span>
    </li> <!-- .product end -->
  </ul> <!-- .row end -->
</div> <!-- .products-list-container -->
```

Comment: This works, but the columns will automatically be forced to have equal heights in a row, right? Is there a way to allow different heights among columns?

Comment: @emrah I don't understanding what you want. Would you like an example? Have you had a look here? http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

Comment: And example to see without writing all the staff would be nice.